# Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have installed maven :

```
C:\Windows\System32>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e405a7528ec3e0dke21dja06; 2015-04-22T13:57:3
7+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I am trying to generate  Jersey glassfish project with the aid of maven prompt but when I type the following:

```
D:\maven>mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archety
pes -DinteractiveMode=false \ -DarchetypeVersion=2.17
```

I am getting this error:

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
>    in this directory (D:\maven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct
>   directory. -> [Help 1]

I dont understand the error: Which project is required here since I am trying to generate one? And how should I create the pom.xml file? I thought it is created by the project generation.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit** when I type it without `\`

```
D:\maven>mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archety
pes  -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeVersion=2.17
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources
@ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources
@ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --
-
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.glassfish.jer
sey.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:2.17)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/archetype
s/maven-archetype-quickstart/2.17/maven-archetype-quickstart-2.17.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.542 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-12T16:39:51+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.3:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
not exist (org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:2.17) -> [
Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption

D:\maven>
```

Comment: Can you try `mvn archetype:generate` without any arguments?
My idea is maybe you didn't specify the right arguments for this command line. (maybe missing archetypeArtifactId). 

Tell me when you're done

Comment: @RPresle: I am getting much of stuff with number but I cant find my flassfish version below just this one `1303: remote -> org.xaloon.archetype:xaloon-archetype-wicket-jpa-glassfish (-)`

Comment: ntains): 598: 1303
Choose org.xaloon.archetype:xaloon-archetype-wicket-jpa-glassfish version:
1: 1.5.0
2: 1.5.1
3: 1.5.2
4: 1.6.0
5: 1.6.1
Choose a number: 5:

Comment: Ok so you're Maven is completely ok, it's just the way you call the command and the content of it. Can you try this  `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archety
pes  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp`. From [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes)

Comment: I am getting the same error 'The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (D:\maven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`

Comment: Maybe you've already seen [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593628/maven-error-no-pom-in-this-project-when-performing-archetypegenerate). Be sure you have no caracter '\'

Comment: @RPresle: I have typed it without `\` please see my edit question part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go for an answer now.

So the first part of your problem was the caracter "\". See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593628/maven-error-no-pom-in-this-project-when-performing-archetypegenerate)

Then for your second problem : it is said   `The desired archetype does
not exist`. This archetype maven-archetype-quickstart doesn't exist in maven repository. Please refer to [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes) to choose the archetype you are looking for and put it in your command.

At the end you command must have at least 2 argument `-DarchetypeGroupId` and `-DarchetypeArtifactId`. For example :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp
```

Comment: At the end of the line what do you mean with code here? it works now I have created it Thanks but I cant import it into eclipse.

Comment: Was a type. Corrected. Can you explain this eclipse thing? here or in an another question an link it here

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve maven ***mvn archetype:generate*** issue "**The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory XXXX**" on windows.

It is **related to how Windows PowerShell interprets the command**

You need to enclose the arguments of *mvn archetype:generate* with **double quotes ("")**.

For example:

```
**mvn archetype:generate 
  "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" 
  "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" 
  "-DgroupId=codingvoding.org"  
  "-DartifactId=java8-features-demo" 
  -B**
```

Also, make sure that you are running this command on **EMPTY directory**.